# iOS: Can i create a static library with all classes (.h & .m) as public?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a bunch of classes that i want to share with others so i thought of creating a static library but i don't want to hide my code. I want to allow them to put change in the library if they want to.

I can share a folder of files but i want to merge all the files into a single package so it's easy to manage and maintain.

Static library generally shows only header (.h) files to users but is it possible to make implementation (.m) files also visible?

I've one more static library which is a dependency for this one. Can i put one static library inside another? or i have to add both files in my project?

I didn't do this library stuff before so am i going in a right direction? or is there any more appropriate way in iOS that can fulfil my requirement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ship the code as a framework and instead of sharing a folder, turn the library into a regular project on GitHub or anywhere else. Add what’s needed to install the library through [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) or [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). Make proper releases with [semantic versioning](http://semver.org), write a proper Changelog.

It’s a lot of stuff to go through for the first time, but it’s a good practice that will pay off. See my [simple goo.gl client](https://github.com/zoul/URLShortener) for an example of such library.

Comment: Thank you! i've successfully created my own Cocoapod project, very helpful.
I've one more question, Shipping code as a framework, Is there any way i can make implementation files (.m) visible to all users or i've to go with (.h) only?

is this a good idea making .m files public? will be there any compilation warnings or errors?

Comment: Good job! There are two options: distributing a static library with headers and distributing the whole thing. I usually opt for the latter, distributing the complete sources. That way other people can make the most of your code.

Comment: Okay, i'll go with second option. Thanks for advising. I've got my answer :)